# XAML menuitem that is visible but not selectable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I'm extremely new to XAML and still learning. I've followed several tutorials on the menu and menuitems but I cannot seem to find a way to add something to a menu and not have it be selectable. I tried adding just a label and it still shows as selectable. I tried setting isenabled to false and it did turn grey, but was still selectable. I tried turning off hittest and that didn't work either. My guess is that this has something to do with setting up a custom style, which I know nothing about. I'm going to head back into the googles and dive into that, but in the mean time I wanted to post here to see if anyone could offer insight as to a good direction to head.

Edit:
Simple example that I tried:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="My Menu">
        <Label Content="Label1"/>                           //Selectable even though it's a label. I would Expect a label to not be selectable.
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1"/>                    //Selectable as it should be.
        <Separator />                                       //Not selectable
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"/>
        <Label Content="Another Label" IsEnabled="False"/>  //Selectable even though it is set to IsEnabled=False.
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Some sample code of what you try to do may attract quick response.

Comment: Setting the IsEnabled property of MenuItem to false should suffice (the item would be disabled & not selectable). I tried this in a sample. Maybe a code sample could help us give you better suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work a bit more like what you want. I added `Focusable="False"` and `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.  Note I had to change the last `<Label>` to `<MenuItem>` since `Focusable="False"` didn't quite do it there.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="My Menu">
        <Label Content="Label1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <Separator />                                       
        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Another Label" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>   
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks so much jschroedl! That solved it perfectly. I tried using Focusable and IsHitTestVisible... but not together :P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article [Menu Control Tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/menu-control/) if you use commands the CanExecute method can grey out the item and make it non-selectable

Comment: cool, thanks. Is there a way to have an item that is not selectable/highlightable without greying it out?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe just have that option just not do anything? or look at the other answer from jschroedl that might also work.