# How to add a non-selectable context menu item as a title in WPF ContextMenu control

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have in my UI some symbols (that represent electric equipments). I implemented a context menu that allows the user to perform some actions.

I would like to add a non-selectable title label at the top of the context menu;

this item **should not** be selected or highlighted with the mouse cursor

Like in this image : [image]

How can I do this ??

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>

        <MenuItem Header="Start" IsEnabled="{Binding ControlPanelViewModel.IsStartEnabled}" Command="{Binding Path=ControlPanelViewModel.StartEscalatorCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Stop" IsEnabled="{Binding ControlPanelViewModel.IsStopEnabled}" Command="{Binding Path=ControlPanelViewModel.StopEscalatorCommand}"/>

        <Separator/>

        <MenuItem x:Name="OpenControl" Header="Control panel..." Command="{Binding OpenControlPanelCommand}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Path Data="M19,4C20.11,4 21,4.9 21,6V18A2,2 0 0,1 19,20H5C3.89,20 3,19.1 3,18V6A2,2 0 0,1 5,4H19M19,18V8H5V18H19Z" Fill="Black" Margin="-5"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML menuitem that is visible but not selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766130/xaml-menuitem-that-is-visible-but-not-selectable)

Comment: @LittleBit no it is not

Comment: How so? Simply add something like `<MenuItem Header="Escalator ID: ESC1A36" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" Background="Gray" Foreground="White"/>` at the top of your `MenuItem`s and it looks/behaves as you described. You may edit your Question if this doesen't fit your needs.

Comment: you are right, but it appears as a menu item and I want to delete the white space that is on the left of the context menu so that the header takes the whole width of the context menu

Comment: What do you mean by `white space that is on the left of the context menu`? Can you add a sketch/image to the question?

Comment: @LittleBit On the Aero theme (Windows 7), there's a small amount of space to the left of each menu item (where an icon would go if available for that item). The solution via the link makes the menu item unclickable but still looks like the rest of the menu items (including the space to the left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the title to the ControlTemplate of the ContextMenu. You can get the default ControlTemplate for the ContextMenu using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676176/1383366), and then modify it to add the title. I've done this below:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
                <mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome Color="#00FFFFFF" Name="Shdw" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="ContextMenuBorder">
                        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly=FrameworkElement, ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer}}" Name="ContextMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0,1,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label>Your title goes here</Label>
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas Width="0" Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="{x:Null}" Name="OpaqueRect" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Fill="#FFF1F1F1" Width="28" Margin="1,2,1,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFE2E3E3" Width="1" Margin="29,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="1" Margin="30,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ContextMenuService.HasDropShadow">
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="Shdw">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Thickness>0,0,5,5</Thickness>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome.Color" TargetName="Shdw">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Color>#71000000</Color>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Trigger.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                        </Trigger.Value>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="ContextMenuScrollViewer">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" ElementName="ContextMenuScrollViewer" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding Path="HorizontalOffset" ElementName="ContextMenuScrollViewer" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Trigger.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                        </Trigger.Value>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContextMenu.Template>

        <MenuItem Header="Start" IsEnabled="{Binding ControlPanelViewModel.IsStartEnabled}" Command="{Binding Path=ControlPanelViewModel.StartEscalatorCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Stop" IsEnabled="{Binding ControlPanelViewModel.IsStopEnabled}" Command="{Binding Path=ControlPanelViewModel.StopEscalatorCommand}"/>

        <Separator/>

        <MenuItem x:Name="OpenControl" Header="Control panel..." Command="{Binding OpenControlPanelCommand}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Path Data="M19,4C20.11,4 21,4.9 21,6V18A2,2 0 0,1 19,20H5C3.89,20 3,19.1 3,18V6A2,2 0 0,1 5,4H19M19,18V8H5V18H19Z" Fill="Black" Margin="-5"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

The key modification was to wrap the `Grid` in a `StackPanel` and add a `Label` with your title above the `Grid`. Because the default ControlTemplate uses Aero, you'll need to reference PresentationFramework.Aero in your project.

Comment: I can't find a way to add the code given in this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf/676176#676176] 
Where should I add the code ?

Comment: @Amibluesky I’ve already done it for you and put it in the code above. The link was just meant to show you where I got the code from.